# Why does jackson ObjectMapper throws ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson, objectmapper

I'm writing simple web app and trying to implement Jackson, but stuck with this error:

```
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
   right on
     `mapper = new ObjectMapper();`
```

Error stack:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at CalculatorServlet.doPost(CalculatorServlet.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Server is tomcat v7, packaging is war, jackson core, annotations and data-bind are v. 2.8.6.

Comment: what does your maven dependencies look like ? Is it deployed as WAR ? Is the library packaged in the war (if you manually open the WAR) ?

Comment: @alexbt I've left my dependencies screenshot

,packaging  is war

Comment: Please always, anywhere on the web, post text as text and not images. Images are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers - it is much more convenient for helpers to work with actual text.

Comment: @halfer okay, sorry, i''ll try my best next time. Have you got any ideas about problem?)

Comment: Don't try better _next time_. Do better _now_. You can edit your question.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis i can't add images by now because of my reputy

Comment: We don't want pictures. Post text. Please read the help center to better understand how to ask a question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, would you add in your XML file in as well?

Comment: @halfer sorry, it says that there's too much code compared to text

Comment: In that case, try cutting down the size of the XML (or the problem in general) by creating the smallest possible project that can demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Also, regarding titles, please use ordinary English sentences, ideally questions, and don't be tempted to add home-made tags. We have a tagging system for that. [More info here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` dependency in your web application:

You have following options

- Within eclipse, right-click on project and obtain a war file (maven > maven > package). The war file should have dependencies included.
- if you are running the project as dynamic web project on a server within eclipse, then you should open the project properties (right click > properties) and select "Deployment Assembly". There click "add", select "build path entries", and choose "maven dependencies".

This will include dependencies and resolve your issue.

Comment: Tell me please, what exactly should i add into this folder? It's empty now.

Should i add there .class file ? Thank you

Comment: @LeopoldStotch Ok. are you building the war file from eclipse?

Comment: yes, i'm starting it locally on tomcat v7

Comment: @LeopoldStotch please have a look i just edited the answer

Comment: wow, thank you so much, you're my hero)